# I am unsure how to get the resistors in parallel from a point. The LHS part is the one I am struggling with

Tags: overleaf, circuitikz, opamp

This is what I have done so far.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
      (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++(-1, 0) coordinate(A)
      (opamp.+) node[ground](B){}
      (opamp.out) to[short,*-o] ++(1, 0) coordinate(C)
      (A) to[R,l_=$4k\Omega$,-o] ++(-2, 0) -- ++(-1, 0) coordinate(D) node[ground]{}
      (A) |- ++(1,1) coordinate[yshift=1ex] (L1) to[R=$40k\Omega$] ++(2,0) -| (opamp.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: When you post a question, please always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. That way other users can help you by copying your code without needing to guess what packages you might be using.

Comment: Even if you have difficulty, you can still input some raw value (even if the connections doesn't look very exact), right? So try to do that first, it would be easier for us to explain how should the coordinate be computed. //

Comment: Hint if you want to try to figure out the coordinate yourself, first can you put a point at the intersection, and give it some name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were quite close to the desired circuit scheme ... Based on my previous answer, possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)     node[op amp] (oa) {}
      (oa.+)    to[short]       ++(0,-1) 
                node[ground](B){}
      (oa.out)  to[short]       ++(0, 2) coordinate(A)
                to[R,l_=\qty{40}{\kilo\ohm}] (A -| oa.-)
                to[short]    (oa.-) 
                to[short,*-*]   ++(-1,0) coordinate(B)
                to[R,l_=\qty{4}{\kilo\ohm}, -o] ++(-2,0) node[left=1mm] {Terminal 2}
      (B)       to[short]    ++(0, 1.5)
                to[R,l_=\qty{15}{\kilo\ohm},-o] ++(-2,0) node[left=1mm] {\qty{-5}{\volt}}
      (B)       to[short]    ++(0,-1.5)
                to[R,l_=\qty{40}{\kilo\ohm},-o] ++(-2,0) node[left=1mm] {\qty{-2}{\volt}}
      (oa.out)  to[short,*-o] ++(1,0) node[right] {$V_o$}
                ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]